# c syntax for choleskey Decomposition

Tags: c

```
double *cholesky(double *A, int n) {
    double *L = (double*)calloc(n * n, sizeof(double));
    if (L == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < (i+1); j++) {
            double s = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                s += L[i * n + k] * L[j * n + k];
            L[i * n + j] = (i == j) ?
                sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s) :
                (1.0 / L[j * n + j] * (A[i * n + j] - s));
        }
        return L;
    }
```

Now my question with this code is a follows, I am trying to see the step by step  but I am getting a bit confused.

when I write

```
for(condition)
    for(condition){
        For(k=0;k<j;k++)
            s += L[i * n + k] * L[j * n + k];
        L[i * n + j] = (i == j) ?
            sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s) :
            (1.0 / L[j * n + j] * (A[i * n + j] - s));

    }
```

This is what I see happening:

First `i = 0` and `j = 0`; then I step further into the code and we get this: `for(k)` loop. Now my first question is this since `j=0` in first instance this for loop does not get evaluated, since `k` is less than `j`.

`for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)`

But what of the kode below this for loop does get evaluated. 
Since `L` is an array of zeros, then `s+=l[0]*l[0]` should equal `0`, but I dont get how the loop did run at all. Next does everything else below the `for(k)` get evaluated?

if so `i==j` is true so `L[i * n + j] = sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s)`(in this case equals 0).

now going back to the top my nest questions becomes since

```
for(condition i )
   for(condition j)
```

don't have brackets does `for(i=1 )` get evaluated following that `for(j)` gets evaluated twice below before `j=0` and `j=i`?

Really would appreciate all the help I could get.

Thank you,

Comment: [Casting calloc is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: What's with the indentation?

Comment: K loop won't run on the first iteration as j == 0. L[0][0] is set. On the second iteration j is 0, 1, and the k loop runs once to modify s.

Comment: Does everything below k loop not run in first iteration?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step and examine its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may be easier to understand if you add all the curly brackets, and convert the ternary operator into an if-else statement:

```
double *cholesky(double *A, int n) {
    double *L = (double*)calloc(n * n, sizeof(double));
    if (L == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // loop A
        for (int j = 0; j < (i+1); j++) { // loop B
            double s = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) { // loop C
                s += L[i * n + k] * L[j * n + k];
            }
            // still in loop B
            if (i == j) {
                L[i * n + j] = sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s);
            } else {
                L[i * n + j] = (1.0 / L[j * n + j] * (A[i * n + j] - s));
            }
        }
    }
    return L;
}
```

The code execution goes like this:

1. *loop A* starts and sets `i = 0`, and assuming `i` is less than `n` it runs
2. *loop B* starts and sets `j = 0`, `j` is less than `i+1` (`1`) so it runs
3. `s = 0`
4. *loop C* starts and sets `k = 0`, but since `k < j` (`0 < 0`) is false, the code in *loop C* does not run
5. The rest of *loop B* then executes:

   ```
   if (i == j) {
       L[i * n + j] = sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s);
   } else {
       L[i * n + j] = (1.0 / L[j * n + j] * (A[i * n + j] - s));
   }
   ```

   Since `i = 0` and `j = 0`, `L[i * n + j]` is set to `sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s)`
6. *loop B* increments `j` to `1`, but since `j < (i+1)` (`1 < 1`) is false, it terminates
7. *loop A* increments `i` to `1`, and assuming `i` is less than `n` it runs
8. *loop B* starts and sets `j = 0`, `j` is less than `i+1` (`2`) so it runs
9. `s` is set to `0`
10. *loop C* starts and sets `k = 0`, but since `k < j` (`0 < 0`) is false, the code in *loop C* does not run
11. The rest of *loop B* runs. `i == j` is false, so `L[i * n + j]` is set to `(1.0 / L[j * n + j] * (A[i * n + j] - s))`
12. *loop B* increments `j` to `1`, and since `j < (i+1)` (`1 < 2`) is true, it runs
13. `s` is set to `0`
14. *loop C* starts and sets `k = 0`, and since `k < j` (`0 < 1`) is true, it runs
15. `s` is incremented by `L[i * n + k] * L[j * n + k]`
16. *loop C* increments `k` to `1`, but since `k < j` (`1 < 1`) is false, it terminates
17. The rest of *loop B* runs. `i == j` is true, so `L[i * n + j]` is set to `sqrt(A[i * n + i] - s)`
18. *loop B* increments `j` to `2`, but since `j < (i+1)` (`2 < 2`) is false, it terminates
19. *loop A* increments `i` to `2`, and assuming `i` is less than `n` it runs
20. ...